# ASP.NET MVC: Unit Tests Error - "The type X exists in both Y and Y"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to test an MVC 3 web project with unit tests but keep on getting error messages. All the error messages seem to start off with a similar one and then moves off to different ones.

The error message that keeps on causing problems is `'The type X exists in both "System.Web.Mvc.dll" and "System.Web.Mvc.dll"'` whenever I put X into the immediate window.

There is only one reference to System.Web.Mvc in the project, and although it links to other projects as well their System.Web.Mvc.dll reference is exactly the same as well.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have two different versions of `System.Web.Mvc.dll`.

Comment: I don't. I have one in %SolutionFile%/Libraries/ASP.NET that all of them are referencing (as far as I've seen and I checked quite well) and the only other one on my harddrive I renamed to `System.Web.Mvc.dll.BAK` so it shouldn't use that one

Comment: Could you also check the GAC as well? Also could you try removing the renamed (*.BAK) from your hard-drive (just to be sure)